# Struggling with an integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration

I'm struggling with the following integral:

$$
\int \int (r_1^2 + r_2^2) \exp \left( -\frac{b (r_1 + r_2)}{a} \right) \, \mathrm{d}V_1 \, \mathrm{d}V_2 
$$

I tried to expand near $r_1 = 0 ;\; r_2 = 0$ and to move to s spherical coordinates, but can't get through. I thought there might be some trick I have forgotten to evaluate integrals like this.

It is related to a diamagnetic susceptibility of the helium atoms.

Answer (score 4):

The exponential part factors into a product of exponentials, the sum splits into a sum of integrals and spherical coordinates just mean $dV_1=4\pi r_1^2\,dr_1$ and analogously for $V_2$. What remains will just be a sum of Gamma integrals, you will only need $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}dx=n!$.